# How to deploy managed/unmanaged C++ libraries properly

Tags: c#, deployment, .net-4.0, c++-cli

I have a console application written mostly in C#, targeting .Net 4. It also uses a C++/CLI library which wraps an unmanaged C++ one. Everything is built in Release mode for x86 platform, except the C++?CLI library which is built in Win32.

So when I invoke the console application on my Win 7 workstation, it works. However, when I move over the folder to my Win 2003 SP2 app server, it does not load, claiming the following:

"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'MyWrapper.dll'".

I found the advice to add the following to my app.config, but it does not help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
```

What am I missing?

Edit: .Net 4 is installed on my Win 2003 SP2 app server, and console apps written in pure C# and targeting .Net 4.0 do work on it.

Edit 2: MyWrapper.dll is in the same folder.

Edit 3: DependencyWalker shows the following dlls are missing: MSVCP100.DLL, MSVCR100.DLL, DWMAPI.DLL. I am installing the redistributable.

Comment: Have you installed .NET 4.0 on the Win2k3 machine?

Comment: Debug the location of the dll your server is trying to use, place the dll in that location, there are many tools to do this.

Comment: @linuxuser27 Net 4 is installed on my Win 2003 SP2 app server, and console apps written in pure C# and targeting .Net 4.0 do work on it.

Comment: @Ramhound  MyWrapper.dll is in the same folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess (if MyWrapper.dll is the Mixed mode assembly): The [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555) is not installed. You can use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find missing DLLs. Start Dependencywalker and open MyWrapper.dll - and you can find any missing DLLs.

Comment: DependencyWalker is a great tool

Comment: @Morten: DependencyWalker shows the following dlls are missing: MSVCP100.DLL, MSVCR100.DLL, DWMAPI.DLL. I guess installing the Redistributable package should take care of it.

Comment: @ArneLund: Yes. It sounds easy, but there is different versions of the redist package. The best is to use the one, on the PC that build MyWrapper.dll (search in Program Files). If you download this package it might be the incorrect version (VS version, SP version, patch version...).

Comment: @Morten: installing the package helped, thank you very much! However, DependencyWalker still shows those DLLs as missing. Can you explain why?

Comment: @ArneLund: No I cannot explain why the DLLs are shown as missing. Sorry. DependencyWalker is a very simple but powerfull tool.

Comment: @Morten: I am not following you on "The best is to use the one, on the PC that build MyWrapper.dll (search in Program Files)". I have searched in, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages, found nothing. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @ArneLund: Try searching for vcredist_x86.exe in your Program Files folder.

Comment: @ArneLund : Check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist` (or `Program Files` sans `(x86)` if you're on a 32-bit Windows installation).

Answer (score 1):

First: is .NET 4 actually installed on your 2003 SP2 server?

Second: is the server actually an x86 server? Could it be an IA64 / Itanium CPU? Because if you pre-optimized for x86 it wouldn't run on such a server. I almost always recommend building for all platforms until you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Third: What other libraries does MyWrapper.dll depend on? It's possible MyWrapper is fine but the other libraries are not loading for some reason. Follow the rabbit down the hole.

Comment: this is a x64 box, Intel Xeon cores